# relation between heartbeat,openais,corosync

Tags: cluster, failover, high-availability, heartbeat, linux-ha

i am planning for high availability on lucid ubuntu, i started with drbd after a simple configuration on drbd I went to heartbeat and had a simple config on it too.

on drbd official site a document told me heartbeat is legacy and i should meet pacemaker instead as CRM.

on pacemaker related documents i understand heartbeat and OpenAis both are cluster infrastructures but openais is more preferred choosed by redhat too, so i went to openais and installed openais after searching with openais i understand that corosync is a project come from openais and it seem that corosync is used with ubuntu instead of openais.

and i want to configure corosync but no config is present where document declare!

1.could any body describe role of pacemaker in relation with openais,corosync ?

2.what's exactly preferred technology for high availability on ubuntu?

3. could you please give a step by step guide to set high availability on ubuntu?

thanks in advance.

Comment: We have less than a tenth of the user base of stack overflow and a much larger remit in terms of products covered by them - sounding annoyed that nobody answered your question in two days makes you sound rather spoiled and childish. As for the downvote, well it wasn't me that gave it but your question isn't very well written and a number of SF users have asked for it to be closed as it's subjective and argumentative. Coming back to SF whining won't do you any favours at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i reached answer on myself! clustering include two part:

1.cluster resource management

2.infrastructure with massaging layer

legacy heartbeat is broken into heartbeat message layer and pacemaker so pacemaker is CRM.

and we have two option on message layer:heartbeat,openais.
openais/corosync is preferred as:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.highavailability.user/32355

There are, however, features in Pacemaker that require OpenAIS which
will work only with Corosync, not Heartbeat. Those features are
concerned with the distributed lock managers used by cLVM (but not
regular LVM), GFS/GFS2, and OCFS2. If you need that functionality, you
must select OpenAIS/Corosync. If you do not, you're free to choose.

as: http://www.clusterlabs.org/wiki/FAQ

Originally Corosync and OpenAIS were the same thing. Then they split into two parts... the core messaging and membership capabilities are now called Corosync, and OpenAIS retained the layer containing the implementation of the AIS standard.

Pacemaker itself only needs the Corosync piece in order to function, however some of the applications it can manage (such as OCFS2 and GFS2) require the OpenAIS layer as well.

so i went to openais/corosync and integrate it with pacemaker.